# Big O Proof by Contradiction

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

> **Question:**
>
> Use a proof by contradiction to show that $5^n$ is not $O(3^n)$

**NOTE:** This is homework, please don't provide an answer, just want to know if I am on the right track.

---

**My Attempt:**

If there exists constants such that $n > 0$ and $c > 0$ then:

$5^n \le C3^n$,

$5^n/3^n = 5/3^n$.

$C \ge 5/3^n$ is a contradiction because $C$ is a constant and there are infinite many values for $n$

---

Is this the correct way of doing it? Thanks a lot

Comment: nope. don't see how you got from the first line to the second

Comment: Im no expert in this, but I guess you want to start with $0<\dfrac {5^n}{3^n} < C$.

Comment: All I did was divide the one side of the equation by 3^n in order to get C by itself.

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but where did $C$ go in the second line?

Comment: Also "there are infinite many values for $n$" is a bad way of arguing. There are infinitely many values for $n$, but $\frac{1}{2^n}$is bounded by a constant.

Comment: The second line is just showing that I raised the whole 5/3 to the exponent of n.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line should either read
$$
5^n/3^n=(5/3)^n
$$
or better yet
$$
\frac{5^n}{3^n}=\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n
$$
and then as Henrik said in the comments, you need to stress that $\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n$ is growing unlimited and goes to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity.

---

If you are into logarithms, maybe a clearer rendering would be
$$
5^n\leq C 3^n\iff n\log5\leq\log C+n\log3\iff n(\log 5-\log 3)\leq\log C
$$
and since $(\log5-\log3)>0$ the LHS goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity.

**NOTE:** It is OK to apply the logarithm on both sides of the inequality, since it is a growing function, thus preserving the direction of the inequality.